# Using python to delete unwanted parts of a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an input file such as

```
[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89984]
'ประยุทธ์' ขอบคุณทุกฝ่าย ยืนยันเจ้าหน้าที่ปฏิบัติตามหลักสากลทุกประการ - ด้านตำรวจยืนยันไม่มีการใช้กระสุนยางและแก๊สน้ำตากระชับพื้นที่ผู้ชุมนุม ระบุสารเคมีผสมน้ำไม่มีอันตราย ใช้เพื่อระุบตัวผู้ชุมนุมดำเนินคดีในอนาคต
เมื่อคืนวันที่ 16 ต.ค. 2563 อนุชา บูรพชัยศรี โฆษกประจำสำนักนายกรัฐมนตรี เปิดเผยว่า พล.อ. ประยุทธ์ จันทร์โอชา นายกรัฐมนตรี และรัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงกลาโหม ขอขอบคุณเจ้าหน้าที่ทุกฝ่าย ประชาชนทุกกลุ่ม และผู้ชุมนุมที่ให้ความร่วมมือกับทางเจ้าหน้าที่ของรัฐในการยุติการชุมนุม
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/about/internship]
Here is some english text
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/node/8813]
Foreigners attended the protest at Thammasat University to show their support for the people of Thailand and their fight for democracy. The use of social media has greatly contributed to the expansion of foreign participation in protests.
A protester with a Guy Fawkes mask at the 19 Sept protest.
[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89903]
ต.ค.62-ก.ย.63 แรงงานไทยในต่างประเทศส่งเงินกลับบ้าน 200,254 ล้านบาท
นายสุชาติ ชมกลิ่น รัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงแรงงาน เปิดเผยว่า นับจากช่วงที่ประเทศไทยเข้าสู่สถานการณ์การแพร่ระบาดของโรคโควิด-19 ส่งผลกระทบต่อการจัดส่งแรงงานไทยไปทำงานต่างประเทศในภาพรวม เนื่องจากหลายประเทศที่เป็นเป้าหมายในการเดินทางไปทำงานของแรงงานไทย ชะลอการรับคนต่างชาติเข้าประเทศ
```

My goal here is to remove every english articles. I have multiple large text files so I want to find an efficient way to get rid of the English articles and keep everything else.

So an example output would look like.

```
[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89984]
'ประยุทธ์' ขอบคุณทุกฝ่าย ยืนยันเจ้าหน้าที่ปฏิบัติตามหลักสากลทุกประการ - ด้านตำรวจยืนยันไม่มีการใช้กระสุนยางและแก๊สน้ำตากระชับพื้นที่ผู้ชุมนุม ระบุสารเคมีผสมน้ำไม่มีอันตราย ใช้เพื่อระุบตัวผู้ชุมนุมดำเนินคดีในอนาคต
เมื่อคืนวันที่ 16 ต.ค. 2563 อนุชา บูรพชัยศรี โฆษกประจำสำนักนายกรัฐมนตรี เปิดเผยว่า พล.อ. ประยุทธ์ จันทร์โอชา นายกรัฐมนตรี และรัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงกลาโหม ขอขอบคุณเจ้าหน้าที่ทุกฝ่าย ประชาชนทุกกลุ่ม และผู้ชุมนุมที่ให้ความร่วมมือกับทางเจ้าหน้าที่ของรัฐในการยุติการชุมนุม
[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89903]
ต.ค.62-ก.ย.63 แรงงานไทยในต่างประเทศส่งเงินกลับบ้าน 200,254 ล้านบาท
นายสุชาติ ชมกลิ่น รัฐมนตรีว่าการกระทรวงแรงงาน เปิดเผยว่า นับจากช่วงที่ประเทศไทยเข้าสู่สถานการณ์การแพร่ระบาดของโรคโควิด-19 ส่งผลกระทบต่อการจัดส่งแรงงานไทยไปทำงานต่างประเทศในภาพรวม เนื่องจากหลายประเทศที่เป็นเป้าหมายในการเดินทางไปทำงานของแรงงานไทย ชะลอการรับคนต่างชาติเข้าประเทศ
```

If you can see, all the English articles are under

```
[headline - https://.../english/...
```

Each article begins with these `[headline` tags which is their URLs. And the English articles happen to have `english` in their URLs.

So now I want to get rid of the English artices. How do I achieve this?

current code

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as inputFile:
   data = inputFile.read().splitlines()

Outputtext = ""

for line in data:
    if line.startswith("[headline"):
        if line.contains("english"):
            #somehow read until the next [headline and do check
        else:
            Outputtext = Outputtext + line + "\n"
    else
```

Comment: So you want to keep every line starting with `[` that as English in it - if it's as simple as any English line starting with a letter A-Z, why not just check each line's first character?

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Please *always* provide a full description of the problems you are encountering. I suspect `line.contains` is giving you trouble. As an aside, `Outputtext = Outputtext + line + "\n"` is *horrible* inefficient. Use a `list`, `.append` to that list, the `str.join` at the end

Comment: @BruceWayne thank you for your comment. Because there might be cases like ```October แรงงานไทยในต่างประเทศส่งเงินกลับบ้าน...``` Also I want to keep every ```[headline``` and its corresponding article text that is NOT english.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you so much for your comment. why would that be inefficient? where would I look into to understand the efficiency more.

Comment: @JirrSawaf because `+` creates *a new whole string* each time, making the entire operation quadratic. It can be done in linear time though. This will of course only matter if your data is large enough, but it is a well-known antipattern that should generally be avoided

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly do this with just Regex. It may need to be tweaked to fit the specific rules for your formatting, though.

```
import re

all_articles = "..."

# match "[headline...english" and everything after till another "[headline"
english_article_regex = r"\[headline[^\]]*\/english[^\]]*].*?(?=(\[headline|$))"

result = re.sub(english_article_regex, "", all_articles, 0, re.DOTALL)
```

Here's the live example:
https://regex101.com/r/heKomA/3

Comment: Thank you for an excellent solution! However this code fails when there's something like ```[random text]``` in the text. Instead, how can we delete until next ```[headline...```?

Comment: @JirrSawaf - I updated the expression accordingly. Now it matches everything up to the next "[headline" or end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you needed to put an extra amount of time into it and you might have solved this problem yourself. When I see your code, I see someone learning programming that is confused about what he needs to do.

You need to think step by step. Like, here, you have a text composed of articles. You want to filter out some articles depending on a condition. What's the first thing you need to do ?

You first need to know how to recognize what is an article. Is an article a pack of 3 lines in your file ? Oh, the size changes, so you need another common factor. They all begin with `[headline` ? Alright. Now, I need to make "groups" of articles. There are a very large number of ways you could do it. But I just wanted to give you an insight as to how you could solve your problem. One step at a time.

Here is a solution to your problem. And it is not the only one, far from it.

```
HELLO
IGNORE
THESE
[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89984]
NOENGLISHTEXT
MULTIPLE
LINES
TEXT
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/about/internship]
Here is some english text
[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/node/8813]
Foreigners attended the protest at Thammasat University to show their support for the people of Thailand and their fight for democracy. The use of social media has greatly contributed to the expansion of foreign participation in protests.
A protester with a Guy Fawkes mask at the 19 Sept protest.
[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89903]
NOENGLISHTEXT SECOND
MULTIPLE
LINES
```

And my solution, in pure python.

```py
def filter_out_english_block(lines: list) -> str:
    filtered_lines = []

    flag = False
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("[headline"):
            if 'english' not in line:
                flag = True
            else:
                flag = False

        if flag:
            filtered_lines.append(line)

    return "".join(filtered_lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("hello.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    print(lines)
    # ['HELLO\n', 'IGNORE\n', 'THESE\n', '[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89984]\n', 'NOENGLISHTEXT\n', 'MULTIPLE\n', 'LINES\n', 'TEXT\n', '[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/about/internship]\n', 'Here is some english text\n', '[headline - https://prachatai.com/english/node/8813]\n', 'Foreigners attended the protest at Thammasat University to show their support for the people of Thailand and their fight for democracy. The use of social media has greatly contributed to the expansion of foreign participation in protests.\n', 'A protester with a Guy Fawkes mask at the 19 Sept protest.\n', '[headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89903]\n', 'NOENGLISHTEXT SECOND\n', 'MULTIPLE\n', 'LINES']

    new_text = filter_out_english_block(lines)
    print(new_text)
    # [headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89984]
    # NOENGLISHTEXT
    # MULTIPLE
    # LINES
    # TEXT
    # [headline - https://prachatai.com/journal/2020/10/89903]
    # NOENGLISHTEXT SECOND
    # MULTIPLE
    # LINES
```

The explanation is :

- I first decide to iterate through the file as a list.
- I decide to store lines only If I have previously seen a condition that suits me (Here, it would be to see the `[headline` line, that **does not** contain the `english` string.
- And my `storing condition` is set by default to False, so that the first lines are ignored until I see a condition that suits me for storing.